# jquery multiply and divide at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Here are my text fields**

```
        <tr>
            <td>Price:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price" id="form_textfield" class="price" autocomplete="off" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Liters:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="liters" id="form_textfield" class="liters" autocomplete="off" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Amount:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="jqueryamount"  id="form_textfield" class="jqueryamount" autocomplete="off" /></td>
        </tr>
```

Currently when you input price and liters, it multiplies them and outputs the answer to jqueryamount textfield it works well. What i want to do is when i type in the amount and the price it will divide the jqueryamount field with the price field and output it to liters field.

**UPDATE FIXED**

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.price').keyup(calculate);
$('.liters').keyup(calculate);
});
function calculate(e)
{
    $('.jqueryamount').val($('.price').val() * $('.liters').val());
}

// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.jqueryamount').keyup(calculate1);
$('.price').keyup(calculate1);
});
function calculate1(e)
{
    $('.liters').val($('.jqueryamount').val() / $('.price').val());
}
```

JUST ADDED A NEW NAME FOR THE DIVIDE FUNCTION... silly me thanks for the help guys

**Here are my javascript**

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.price').keyup(calculate);
$('.liters').keyup(calculate);
});
function calculate(e)
{
    $('.jqueryamount').val($('.price').val() * $('.liters').val());
}

// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.jqueryamount').keyup(calculate);
$('.price').keyup(calculate);
});
function calculate(e)
{
    $('.liters').val($('.jqueryamount').val() / $('.price').val());
}
```

My problem is when adding the divide function the multiplication part will no longer work, i can no longer type inside the liters textfield it gives me NaN error.

Comment: keep the functions name different calculate and calculate1, also when receiving value from field use parseFloat like this parseFloat($('.jqueryamount').val())

Comment: @Neo i get NaN error on one of the textfields but the multiplication seems fine just the division im having trouble with. Even with parseFloat

Comment: that is because you are calling $('.price').keyup(calculate); and this particular time there may or may not be a value in amount field...hence a no divided by a "blank" is giving NaN...i hope yu get it.

Comment: try giving all fields a 0 value by default in start and then check.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseFloat()` function after the get the value from input, which converts string to number.

When you put the value price and amount the liters would show like this.

```
$('.price').keyup(calculateLiters, calculateAmount);
$('.jqueryamount').keyup(calculateLiters);
$('.liters').keyup(calculateAmount);


function calculateLiters(e) {
    price = parseFloat($('.price').val());
    amount = parseFloat($('.jqueryamount').val());
    if(!isNaN(price) && !isNaN(amount)){
        $('.liters').val(amount / price);
    }
}

function calculateAmount(e) {
    price = parseFloat($('.price').val());
    liters = parseFloat($('.liters').val());

    if(!isNaN(price) && !isNaN(liters)){
        $('.jqueryamount').val(price  * liters);
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jVaNC/2/)

Comment: I think parseFloat would be a better choice here.

Comment: i cant type into the field where i want a division

Comment: i just want to be able to switch in between the textfields, if they want to input amount and price the liters will answer, if they fill up the price and liters the amount will answer.

Answer (score -1):

I swapped some class names and id's to make code more efficient.

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td>Price:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form_textfield" autocomplete="off" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Liters:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="liters" id="liters" class="form_textfield" autocomplete="off" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Amount:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jqueryamount"  id="jqueryamount" class="form_textfield" autocomplete="off" /></td>
</tr>
```

**Javascript**

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form_textfield').keyup(calculate);
});

function calculate()
{
    $('#jqueryamount').val($('#price').val() * $('#liters').val());
    $('#liters').val($('#jqueryamount').val() / $('#price').val());
}
```

Here is a working demo. http://jsfiddle.net/vnaDK/

Comment: You did not consider about amount when user changes the liters.